# Razor _Layout Page - Display Message After Post Form

Tags: razor, razor-pages

I have the following form on my razor _Layout.cshtml page

```
<form method="post" class="contact-form" id="footer-cf">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
     <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
     <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
     <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
@I_Want_A_Success_Message_Property_Here
```

I handle the OnPost() on my index.cshtml page.

How can I get a message into a property to display in the custom message property after the OnPost() method is finished handling the POST on the index.cshtml page please?

thanks

Comment: Just look at how it works for the _StatusMessage.cshtml standard partial view. You can replicate that behavior changing the variable used to display the _StatusMessage.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ViewData` dictionary:

**Index.cshtml.cs**:

```cs
public void OnPost()
{
    // ...
    ViewData["message"] = "custom message";
    // ...
}
```

**Index.cshtml**:

```
@if (ViewData.TryGetValue("message", out var message))
{
    <div class="alert alert-primary">@message</div>
}
```